# Repeated letters in a word

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am forming words of length N from an alphabet of p letters.
What is the probability of getting exactly k non-repeated letters?
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Could you perhaps add more context to your question, such as what you have tried or what difficulties you have encountered?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution

Comment: @GuilhermeThompson I do not see how that is related to this problem.

Answer (score 2):

(*As an aside, I assumed that with alphabet $\{a,b,c\}$ the word aaabaaa is said to have exactly one non-repeated letter, namely $b$ instead of two non-repeated letters $b$ and $c$.  I.e. I assume that for a letter to be called non-repeating, it must occur exactly once as opposed to zero or once.  If that is not the intention, I can fix the post at a later time.*)

Via inclusion exclusion:

Let $f(A,b)$ denote the number of ways to have a word of length $A$ with $b$ available letters such that all letters occur either zero or strictly more than one time each.

Let $E_i$ represent the event that the $i^{th}$ letter of the alphabet of $b$ letters occurs exactly once in the word of length $A$.  We have $f(A,b) = |\bigcap E_i^c| = b^A - |\bigcup E_i| \\= b^A - bA(b-1)^{A-1}+\binom{b}{2}A(A-1)(b-2)^{A-2}-\binom{b}{3}A(A-1)(A-2)(b-3)^{A-3}+\dots$

$=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i \binom{b}{i}A^{\underline{i}}(b-i)^{A-i}$

Each term of which comes from the inclusion-exclusion expansion of $|\bigcup E_i|$ noting that $|E_1\cap \cdots \cap E_n|$, in alphabetical order pick the locations occupied by the $n$ letters guaranteed to be used exactly once, and for all remaining $A-n$ spaces, fill each with one of the $b-n$ available letters without regard to number of occurrences.

(*note: here $A^{\underline{i}}$ denotes the falling factorial $A(A-1)(A-2)\cdots(A-i+1)$*)

So, the number of words of length $N$ of an alphabet with $p$ letters with exactly $k$ occurrences of letters occurring exactly once and all other letters occurring zero or strictly more than one time each is found via multiplication principle as:

- Pick which $k$ letters occur exactly once.  $\binom{p}{k}$ choices
- Pick which spaces in the word they occupy.  $\binom{N}{k}$ choices
- Pick the order in which they appear.  $k!$ choices
- For the remaining $N-k$ spaces and the remaining $p-k$ unused letters, fill the spaces with a word where all letters are used zero or strictly more than one time each.  $f(N-k, p-k)$ choices

There are then $\binom{p}{k}\binom{N}{k}k!f(N-k,p-k)$ possible words satisfying the desired properties.  There are $p^N$ different words possible in the sample space.

The probability is then $\dfrac{\binom{p}{k}\binom{N}{k}k!f(N-k,p-k)}{p^N}$